# set filter to - INLIST - Visual Foxpro 7

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I am working on some legacy code, and I have the following wonderful issue.  I am hoping some FoxPro experts can help!

The infrastructure of this legacy system is setup so that I have to use the built-in expression engine to return a result set, so no go on the SQL (i know that would be so much easier!)

Here is the issue.

I need to be able to do something like

```
PUBLIC ARRAY(20) ArrayOfValuesToFilterBy

SELECT dataTable 
SET FILTER TO logicalField = .T. and otherField NOT INLIST(ArrayOfValuesToFilterBy)
```

However, I know this wont work, I just need the equivalency...not using SQL.

I can generate the list of values to filter by via SQL, just not the final record select due to the legacy infrastructure constraint.

Thanks!

Comment: For anyone wondering, my exact code after applying the ASCAN looked like this...  SELECT gly
  set filter to gly_is_csh and ASCAN( pRestrictedVendors, gly_srcdsc) = 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a logical field you do not have to do explicit

set filter to Logicalfield = .t.

you can just do

set filter to LogicalField
or
set filter to NOT LogicalField

Next, on the array.  VFP has a function ASCAN() which will scan an array for a value, if found, will return the row number within the array that matches what you are looking for.

As for arrays... ex:
DIMENSION MyArray[3]
MyArray[1] = "test1"
MyArray[2] = "something"
MyArray[3] = "anything else"

? ASCAN( MyArray, "else" )  && this will return 0
? ASCAN( MyArray, "anything else" )  && this will return 3

If you are doing a "set filter", the array needs to be "in scope" for the duration of the filter.  If you set filter in a procedure the array exists, leave the procedure and the array is gone, you're done.

So, you could do

```
set filter to LogicalField and ASCAN( YourArray, StringColumnFromTable ) > 0
```

Now, if you want a subset to WORK WITH, you can do a SQL-Select and pull the data into a CURSOR (temporary read-write table) that has the same capabilities of the original table (except auto-increment when adding)...

I typically name my temporary cursors prefixed with "C_" for "CURSOR OF" so when I'm working with tables, I know if its production data, or just available for temp purposes for quicker display, presentation, extractions from other origins as needed.

```
use in select( "C_FinalRecords" )
select * from YourTable ;
   where LogicalField ;
     and ASCAN( YourArray, StringColumnFromTable ) > 0;
   into cursor C_FinalRecords READWRITE
```

Then, you can just use that...

```
select C_FinalRecords
scan
   do something with the record, or values of it...
endscan
```

or.. bind to a grid in a form, etc...

Comment: The ASCAN worked perfectly... and thanks for the tip about the Logical, very thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

The INLIST() function takes an expression to search for and up to 24 expressions of the same data type to search.

```
SELECT dataTable 
SET FILTER TO logicalField = .T. AND NOT INLIST(otherField, 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4')
```

Comment: This will not do what I want.  I know what the INLIST() function does, but I cannot specify hard parameters such as this at runtime.  @DRapp had the perfect solution.  Thanks for trying though Dave!

Answer (score 0):

I am making some assumptions here, that what you want to do is create a filter with a dynamic in list statement ? If this is correct have a play with this example :-

```
lcList1="ABCD"
lcList2="EFGH"
lcList3="IJKL"
lcList4="MNOP"
lcList5="QRST"

lcFullList=""
lcFullList=lcFullList+"'"+lcList1+"',"
lcFullList=lcFullList+"'"+lcList2+"',"
lcFullList=lcFullList+"'"+lcList3+"',"
lcFullList=lcFullList+"'"+lcList4+"',"
lcFullList=lcFullList+"'"+lcList5+"'"



lcField="PCode"

lcFilter="SET FILTER TO INLIST ("+lcField+","+lcFullList+")"
```

The results of the above would create the following filter statement and store it in lcFilter

SET FILTER TO INLIST (PCode,'ABCD','EFGH','IJKL','MNOP','QRST')

you can then use macro substitution

```
Select dataTable
&lcFilter
```

Bear in mind that there is likely to be some limitations on how many items you can define in a INLIST() statement

Comment: Thanks for the response Hugh, this would work to a certain extent, assuming I knew about filter at the time.  However, the ASCAN method which was selected as the answer is superior, as there is no limitation on the number of literals you can match, and it takes less code to accomplish the result.